# How do I get the value of a persistent variable with `variable_get()`?

Tags: 7, configuration

How do I get the value of a persistent variable with `variable_get()`? Does the function save the value on a database table or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value use:

```
$valueVar = variable_get('myvar');
```

It is saved on a generic database table called [prefix]_variable, if you are not using prefix, the name of the table is **variable**. Look at: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2009-05-14/help-which-table-is-the-variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable_set() to set the value and that will store it in the database. e.g.

```
variable_set('myvar',123);
```

Then to retreive it:

```
$myvar = variable_get('myvar');
```

You could create a page with a form to allow CMS users to change the values of your variables. See this for examples: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_settings_form/7.x

Answer (score 0):

[`variable_get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7.x) only retrieves the value of a persistent variable; it doesn't save its value as that is the task for [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7.x).

Actually, `variable_get()` gets the persistent variable value from the global [`$conf`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21globals.php/global/conf/7.x) which is initialized from the following code in [`_drupal_bootstrap_variables()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_variables/7.x).

```
  global $conf;

  // Initialize the lock system.
  require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('lock_inc', 'includes/lock.inc');
  lock_initialize();

  // Load variables from the database, but do not overwrite variables set in settings.php.
  $conf = variable_initialize(isset($conf) ? $conf : array());
```

The code in [`variable_initialize()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_initialize/7.x) first tries to load the persistent variable values from the cache, and then load the values from the database (the *variable* database table).

```
  if ($cached = cache_get('variables', 'cache_bootstrap')) {
    $variables = $cached->data;
  }
  else {
    // Cache miss. Avoid a stampede.
    $name = 'variable_init';
    if (!lock_acquire($name, 1)) {

      // Another request is building the variable cache.
      // Wait, then re-run this function.
      lock_wait($name);
      return variable_initialize($conf);
    }
    else {
      // Proceed with variable rebuild.
      $variables = array_map('unserialize', db_query('SELECT name, value FROM {variable}')
        ->fetchAllKeyed());
      cache_set('variables', $variables, 'cache_bootstrap');
      lock_release($name);
    }
  }
  foreach ($conf as $name => $value) {
    $variables[$name] = $value;
  }
  return $variables;
```

To answer the values of persistent variables can be stored:

- In the global `$conf` initialized in the settings.php file (which means in memory)
- In the cache, which isn't necessarily stored in the database, especially if there are third-party modules that change the cache functions
- In the *variable* database table, when saved using `variable_set()`